# Grails controllers being installed automatically & causing 500 Server Error on war deployment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, grails, gradle

I've created a Grails app in Eclipse that is built by Gradle.  I have not created any controllers myself, so I expect to see  an empty page when I use run-app (i.e. a Welcome to Grails page with no controllers listed).  However, I get:

[image]

What are these two controllers and why have they been added automatically?

I ask, as when I deploy the app via a WAR file onto a Dockerized Tomcat server running on AWS Elasticbeanstalk, I get a 500 Server Error that is caused by the following:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: No signature of method: gsp_myApp_layoutsmain_gsp.assetPath() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[src:favicon.ico]]
```

When I run-app and run-war, I get no problems (just the strange controllers listed).  I think this may mean that perhaps there is a plugin not being installed on the Tomcat server that is required and that has been installed automatically on my local machine?  Incidentally, I get the same 500 error when running the Dockerized Tomcat server locally, so the problem is not with AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat moot since you found the real error, but some background info regardless:

If you just search in your project root you'll find those controllers - they're both contributed by plugins in your app, so they're hiding in plain sight in your `target` directory.

Plugins are specified in `BuildConfig.groovy` and the initial file generated when you run `create-app` (or do something to cause your IDE to run that script for you) includes a set of initial plugins that you're likely to want; Hibernate for persistence, Tomcat for the embedded web server, etc. Once your requirements stabilize somewhat and you are making more controlled changes to your database, you'll want something like Liquibase to manage that for you, so the `database-migration` plugin is included, and it's the source of `DbdocController`. You should also be managing static UI resources to maximize real and apparent front-end performance, so the `asset-pipeline` plugin is added (and some of its addon plugins are included commented out as suggestions). That's the source of the other controller.

Answer (score 0):

Answer detailed here: [Grails Asset Pipeline causing server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420925/grails-asset-pipeline-causing-server-error)

The issue is in being very careful when using Gradle to build the Grails app to ensure that the war files produced by run-war and 'gradle war' are the same (which they weren't).