# Grails Asset Pipeline causing server error

Tags: tomcat, grails, asset-pipeline

I have created a Grails app with no custom controllers that I have deployed using a Tomcat via Docker.  The app runs ok (run-app and run-war) on my local machine, but not when I deploy using Tomcat.

I get the following stack trace, any idea of the cause please?

```
2014-10-17 08:08:04,158 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout : main
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.rethrowRenderException(GroovyPageView.java:179)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutView.renderTemplate(GrailsLayoutView.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderWithinGrailsWebRequest(AbstractGrailsView.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractGrailsView.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.doHead(HttpServlet.java:243)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: No signature of method: gsp_gradleGrailsApp_layoutsmain_gsp.assetPath() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[src:favicon.ico]]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.createGroovyPageException(GroovyPageView.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.handleException(GroovyPageView.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderTemplate(GroovyPageView.java:75)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderWithinGrailsWebRequest(AbstractGrailsView.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractGrailsView.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:69)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: gsp_gradleGrailsApp_layoutsmain_gsp.assetPath() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[src:favicon.ico]]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesMetaUtils.methodMissingForTagLib(GroovyPagesMetaUtils.groovy:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesMetaUtils$_registerMethodMissingForGSP_closure1.doCall(GroovyPagesMetaUtils.groovy:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:933)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1256)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1209)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1111)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at gsp_gradleGrailsApp_layoutsmain_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(gsp_gradleGrailsApp_layoutsmain_gsp.groovy:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.executeClosure(GroovyPageTagBody.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.captureClosureOutput(GroovyPageTagBody.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.GroovyPageTagBody.call(GroovyPageTagBody.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib.captureTagContent(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib.captureTagContent(SitemeshTagLib.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib$_closure1.doCall(SitemeshTagLib.groovy:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTagLibClosure(GroovyPage.java:501)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:419)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPage$invokeTag$4.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gsp_gradleGrailsApp_layoutsmain_gsp.run(gsp_gradleGrailsApp_layoutsmain_gsp.groovy:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.doWriteTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:217)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderTemplate(GroovyPageView.java:71)
    ... 40 more
```

EDITED to include main.gsp listing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
        <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
        <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
        <g:layoutHead/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><asset:image src="grails_logo.png" alt="Grails"/></a></div>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
        <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp? From the stacktrace it appears to be having problems with the favicon.ico. Can you verify that file exists in your project as well?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thanks, favicon.ico exists in the target/assets directory, but does not appear to be being copied to the war file.  I am copying the war file to the Tomcat webapps directory when deploying and I guess the error is due to the server not being able to find the favicon.ico file.  Do you know why the war file would not include the assets directory? https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/wiki/Why-asset-pipeline-over-grails-resources-plugin states: "In production, the asset-pipeline compiles your assets on war create. ... This folder is then copied into your war file."

Comment: Do you have anything defined for `grails.assets.excludes` in your `Config.groovy`? What version of Grails and the asset pipeline plugin are you using?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thank you very much for the initial clue, the problem was in using Gradle & Grails together, detailed below.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it sorted out. Sometimes talking things through is all that is needed. #grails on chat.freenode.org is a good place for that too (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, found it.  The issue is that the project is being built by the Gradle Grails plugin when deploying.  There is a one liner in their docs ([Gradle Grails plugin](http://grails.github.io/grails-gradle-plugin/docs/manual/guide/usage.html)):

> Using the Grails Gradle Plugin bypasses the normal Grails application
>   build framework in favor of Gradle. The consequence of this is that
>   the BuildConfig.groovy is no longer consulted for repository or
>   dependency information.

Therefore plugins that were being included from BuildConfig.groovy are being ignored and it was being built using the plugins defined in build.gradle (which did not include the asset pipeline plugin).  Thus the war file being created by 'grails run-war' was different to that created by 'gradle war'.  Unzipping the 2 war files showed the difference in structure.  Moving the dependencies from BuildConfig.groovy to build.gradle meant the war file was built correctly.

Thanks to @JoshuaMoore for the initial hint, that's what put me on the right track.