# Error applying layout : main

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am new to grails and am trying to deploy a helloworld grails application to tomcat.

I created the war file and then placed the war file under webapps directory in tomcat. Then I started the tomcat from bin folder and traced the logs. The application was deployed without any errors in the log.

Now when I try to access the application from the browser I get this error

```
Error 500 - Internal Server Error.

Error applying layout : main
```

Note: When I do a grails run-app, the application run perfectly.

Can someone help me out on what this is related to and how I can fix it.

```
EDIT:
2016-03-07 16:34:27,260 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] ERROR StackTrace  - Full   Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout : main
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.rethrowRenderException(GroovyPageView.java:179)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:78)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutView.renderTemplate(GrailsLayoutView.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderWithinGrailsWebRequest(AbstractGrailsView.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractGrailsView.java:33)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:437)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: No signature of method: gsp_helloworld_layoutsmain_gsp.assetPath() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[src:favicon.ico]]
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.createGroovyPageException(GroovyPageView.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.handleException(GroovyPageView.java:104)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView.renderTemplate(GroovyPageView.java:75)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderWithinGrailsWebRequest(AbstractGrailsView.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractGrailsView.java:33)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.SpringMVCViewDecorator.render(SpringMVCViewDecorator.java:69)
... 37 more
```

Thanks

Comment: can you attach full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: That is what i get in my browser ... and no errors in the tomcat logs.

Comment: which Tomcat, JDK, OS and Grails versions do you use?

Comment: apache-tomcat-6.0.44
jdk : 1.7.0_51
Grails version: 2.4.3

Comment: Paste content of tomcat_installation_folder/logs/stacktrace.log

Comment: added it in my description as an edit

Comment: well it says that you are doing the render or respond part incorrectly. Check if you have specified right path to render page. Hence in general check if your war contains the gsp files

Comment: Are you using grails gradle plugin? What plugins did you add to new application? It may be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420925/grails-asset-pipeline-causing-server-error

Comment: @droggo I did not add any plugin. It is simply a helloworld plugin created using grails create-app helloworld

After that I added a controller to render "Hello World" string and show it in the browser. Thats all !!

Comment: Do you build war using `grails war` command? It seems that result WAR is  missing `asset-pipeline` plugin jars and this causes this error, but I don't know why this could happen. Can you put this project online?

Comment: @droggo I simply followed this blog to create the project http://grailslover.blogspot.in/2011/12/hello-world-application.html

Then did a grails war to create the war file and deploy in the tomcat.

Comment: Sorry, can help with that more. I recommend that you connect to Grails Slack channel and ask there, maybe someone faced it already - if there is really no more modified, this looks like a serious bug in this version. Another recommendation is to not start with old version, either start with newest Grails 2.5.x or even better Grails 3.1.x

Answer (score 0):

Problem is connected with stacktrace line: `No signature of method: gsp_helloworld_layoutsmain_gsp.assetPath() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[src:favicon.ico]]`.

So you provide wrong type of argument to your layout view in `views/layouts/main.gsp` during referencing to `favicon.ico`.